# iOS remove all HTML tags except <p>

Tags: html, ios, regex

I am trying to remove HTML tags from a string for displaying a label. Pulling this string down from a JSON webservice but not too sure about removing these tags. I know that using

```
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
```

will remove all the tags, however I am looking to remove all except a tag starting with

```
<p style=""> Content I want here </p>
```

Can somebody explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this regex:

```
<[^p][^>]*\/?[^p]>
```

Instead of:

```
<[^>]+>
```

see demo http://regex101.com/r/iZ3wY0